# How to execute groupby with streaming partitions in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I'm trying to do a groupby over a streaming partition. When I'm using a sliding window and the partition id the grouped data are empty.

For example:

```py
df = (spark_session.readStream\
                   .format("kafka")\
                   .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka)\
                   .option("subscribe", input_topic)\
                   .load().selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)",
                                      "CAST(partition as INT)"))
# Expand value to get tm_ms then
df = df.withColumn("ts", from_unixtime(col("ts_ms"), format="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"))\
                 .withColumn("ts", col("ts").cast(TimestampType()))


df = df.withColumn("value", struct("*"))
       .withWatermark("ts", "1 hour")\
       .groupBy(window("ts", "1 second"), "partition")\
       .agg(collect_list("value").alias("value"))
...

df = df.select("partition", "key", 
               to_json(struct([c for c in health_tags.columns
                               if c not in {"partition", 'key'}])).alias("value"))\
       .withColumn("partition", col("partition").cast("integer"))

df = df.writeStream \
       .format("kafka")\
       .outputMode("update")\
       .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka)\
       .option("topic", output_topic)\
       .start()
```

When I'm removing the sliding window -`window("ts", "1 second")`-, pyspark is able to groupby, but I believe it keeps the state and continuously expands the size of the group as new data arrive.

Is my understanding correct? If yes, how can I use the sliding window along with the partition number to groupby?

Thank you

My expectation is that I will be able to group the data per partition with a sliding window. In addition I want to avoid any shuffling between spark executors.

Comment: Did you use writeStream to write your stream out? If so, could you share your writestream options, especially the outputmode?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that part. I updated the example to reflect the write stream logic as well.